# Create a list by combining two vectors element-wise

Tags: r, list

I'm trying to produce a list by combining two vectors of the same length element-wise. Here's a reproducible example.

```
a <- c(1:3)
b <- c("a", "b", "c")
```

Using these two vectors, I hope to create the following:

```
goal <- list(list(1, "a"), list(2, "b"), list(3, "c"))
```

I've tried a few different ways, but nothing seems to work.

```
list(as.list(a), as.list(b)) # Not working
as.list(as.list(a), as.list(b)) # Not working as well
as.list(outer(a,b, paste)) # Not working
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use `Map` -

```
Map(list, a, b)

#[[1]]
#[[1]][[1]]
#[1] 1

#[[1]][[2]]
#[1] "a"


#[[2]]
#[[2]][[1]]
#[1] 2

#[[2]][[2]]
#[1] "b"


#[[3]]
#[[3]][[1]]
#[1] 3

#[[3]][[2]]
#[1] "c"
```

Or `map2` in `purrr` -

```
purrr::map2(a, b, list)
```

Comment: or `mapply(list, a, b, SIMPLIFY = FALSE)`